# Batch Script inserts un-needed spaces padding special character

Tags: batch-file

I have a very simple script that inputs a user name and password. Some passwords contain special characters such as:!,@,#,$,^,&,*,(,),_. The issue is when they enter one of these characters it pads the character with blank spaces on either side inside the variable.

Here is my code and an example:

```
echo Enter UserName:
set/p user=
echo Enter Password:
set/p pass=
echo %pass%
net use R: \\serverhere /USER:%user% %pass%
```

if I entered: `Test!Password` for my password,
it would output: `Test ! Password` for %pass% in the net use command which causes issues

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your sample is wrong! Entering `Test!Password` results in the output of `Test!Password` or if delayed expansion is enabled into `TestPassword`. There aren't spaces

Comment: So the issue is when I try to use the variable in the net use command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there are problems with injected spaces, but you get problems with special characters at all.

So the best way is to use delayed expansion, as it doesn't care about special characters.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Enter UserName:
set/p user=
echo Enter Password:
set/p pass=
echo !pass!
net use R: \\serverhere /USER:!user! !pass!
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! I would have never figured that out